# Moment js formatting time not working correctly

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have question, how to format '90:33' - 'mm:ss' into '01:30:33' - 'hh:mm:ss'?
Moment js dont format 90 minutes, because it more than 60, and result is 'Invalid Date'
I tryed this:

```
console.log(moment('90:33', ['mm:ss', 'hh:mm:ss']).format('hh:mm:ss'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say 90 is invalid as the minutes parameter. I would do something like this:

```
// Assuming duration is a string in the format "mm:ss" e.g. "90:33"
var parts = duration.split(":");
var minutes = duration[0];
var seconds = duration[1];


var d = moment.duration({minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds});
var as_string = d.hours() + ":" + d.minutes() + ":" + d.seconds(); // "1:30:33"
```